# From UTC time to a readable format usin haml

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

Im currently working with the mirror quick start demo from Google Glass, which is built in Ruby using Sinatra to make the web app. Also it uses haml to render the website. My question is:

I can get the date from the timeline card using

```
Rack::Utils.escape_html(timeline_item.created)
```

But it give me back the UTC time. I already tried using strftime but its not working (it says it's a String).

Yeah I'm new on this, Any help? please??

heres the code of the layout file on haml

```
.span4


%table.table.table-bordered
    %tbody
      %tr
        %th Attachments
        %td
          - if timeline_item.attachments.length > 0
            - timeline_item.attachments.each do |attachment|
              %img{src: "/attachment-proxy?timeline_item_id=#{timeline_item.id}&attachment_id=#{attachment.id}"}
          - else
            .muted None
      %tr
        %th Text
        %td= Rack::Utils.escape_html(timeline_item.text)
      %tr
        %th HTML
        %td= Rack::Utils.escape_html(timeline_item.created)

      %tr
        %td(colspan="2")
          %form.form-inline(method="post" action="/delete-item")
            %input(type="hidden" name="id" value="#{timeline_item.id}")
            %button.btn.btn-block.btn-danger(type="submit") Delete
```

Answer (score 0):

i suspect this might help

```
%td= timeline_item.created.strftime("%B %d, %Y")
```

meaning, don't use the `escape_html` thing on your time objects, that will convert it into a `String` and you'll get the crash you had